# cannot get latest charm revision when ttying to deploy a local charm

Tags: juju

When trying to deploy a local charm I get the following error:

```
error: cannot get latest charm revision: no charms found matching "local:precise/devenv"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth double checking that your metadata.yaml file is correct. First check that it's valid yaml and then double check that it follows the same format as some of the existing charms in the charmstore

Comment: Does `charm proof` work for verifying metadata yaml?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Problem I had was that I accidentally copy/pasted white space in my config.yaml file.
Make sure your config.yaml is uniform and has the same structure from beginning to end.